# Spring : how to get multiple datasource with GenericDao?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, transactions

i have a web application using Spring 3.1.1. 
We have a genericDao using JdbcTemplate. Datasource is injecting like this in the GenericDaoImpl.

```
public class GenericDaoImpl<T extends Serializable> implements GenericDao<T> {

protected Class<T> entityClass;

protected JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Autowired
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}

....

@Override
public List<T> findAll(String sql, ParameterizedRowMapper<T> mapper, Object... args) {
    return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, mapper, args);
}

}
```

This is a simple DAO.

```
@Repository
public class ElementDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<Element> implements ElementDao {

    private static ParameterizedRowMapper<Element> mapper = new ParameterizedRowMapper<Element>() {...};

    public List<Element> findChildren(int id) {
        sql = "SELECT....";
        return findAll(sql, mapper, new Object[] {id});
    }

}
```

For moment, with unique datasource, it is working perfectly.
The applicationContext is configured with annotation.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/...."/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

Now i have to integrate a new DAO still using genericDao, but working on another database (so another datasource).

I use the @Transactionnal in service. And i read on spring documentation that we can give a qualifier to the transaction in order to select the good transaction manager.

So, i create a new datasource, a new transaction manager...

```
<bean id="firstDS" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/...."/>
</bean>

<bean id="secondDS" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/...."/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="firstDS"/>
</bean>

<bean id="txManagerSecond" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="secondDS"/>
    <qualifier value="txSecond"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

and on my new Service, i have added the value to the @Transactionnal annotation :

```
 @Transactionnal("txSecond")
```

To resume, i have 4 classes to manage the new database : Interface for service, Implementation for service with @Transactionnal("txSecond"), Interface for DAO, Implementation for DAO based on genericDao which has a JdbcTemplate object created on an injected Datasource.

I created a Junit test, but for moment, i block on an exception  : NoSuchBeanDefinitionException : no Unique bean of type javax.sql.DataSource is defined. Expected Single matching bean but found 2 (firstDs, SecondDs).

I think the pb is the genericDao but not sure.

How to manage that ?

Thank you.

Comment: Try @Resource(name="firstDS") Instead of the Autowired. @Resource will try first to match by name so it is faster and safer

Comment: Oups...I didn't see your comment. Yeah, i think i will externalize the setter of Datasource. I will keep the genericDao, and create some genericDaoXxx which extends from the first one. In these genericDaoXxx i will paste the setter with your solution `@Resource(name="xxxDS)`. Seems good ?

Answer (score 3):

set manually your dataSource on each bean in your configuration file

```
<bean id="elementDao" class="ElementDaoImpl" autowire="byName">
   <property name="datasource" ref="datasource2">
</bean>
```

An other solution : play with the "alias" http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-java-bean-aliasing

Comment: ah ? i was with a component scan configuration. So i don't declare any bean, all are annotated `@Repository, @Service or @Component` and we add each package which will be scanned.

Comment: Adding 2 transactions has nothing to see with setting your datasource (which is @Autowired)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that while autowiring  the datasource ,you have not specified any qualifier.

```
 @Autowired


public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
```

}

So, if you need both your datasources in the same class, configure them using two different setter injections and provide appropriate qualifier in each case.

Answer (score 0):

By default autowired annotation maps by **type** of bean so one has to use **qualifier("bean id")** in order to let spring container know which bean to wire when multiple beans of the same type exist in config xml.

Answer (score 0):

There is more elegant solution than adding qualifiers.

[Spring: how to hide bean from dependency injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169230/spring-how-to-hide-bean-from-dependency-injection/)

[Autowiring two beans implementing same interface - how to set default bean to autowire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534053/autowiring-two-beans-implementing-same-interface-how-to-set-default-bean-to-au)